# issue with toggle- jumps to top of page when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a toggle function like this:

```
$('ul.internal-nav-list li ').on('click', function () {
        $(this).find('.internal-sub-list li ').toggle();
```

The issue is that when you click to toggle the submenu the page jumps to the top. So I tried using

```
$('ul.internal-nav-list li ').on('click', function (e) {
        $(this).find('.internal-sub-list li ').toggle();
            e.preventDefault();
```

Which fixes the problem, however then the links of the submenu don't work. 
Does anybody know a workaround this?

**Update**

this is the html

```
<ul class="internal-nav-list">
                        <li><a href="#">applications</a>
                            <ul class="internal-sub-list">
                                <li><a href="../sos.aspx">Structures</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../tanks.aspx">Containment Areas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../pumps.aspx">Pumps</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../hex.aspx">Heat Exchangers</a></li>  
                            </ul> 
                        </li>
```

Comment: And what is your HTML?

Answer (score 2):

There might be a better way, but without HTML it is harder to help you out. But you can check to make sure it is not an anchor being clicked

```
if (!$(e.target).is(".internal-sub-list a")) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Updated the question to include the html

Answer (score 2):

Add e.preventDefault() on the anchor links that doesn't need to be active links (I believe in your li you have also an a href="#" element).

As a global fix you can have something like:

```js
$('a[href="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```